# How to transform powershell json response to csv

Tags: json, powershell, api, csv

This is my PowerShell which is calling an API and returning a JSON response.

```
$output = Get-SurveyParticipents `
 -url "https://orxsurveys.limequery.com/admin/remotecontrol" `
 -session $sessionKey `
 -id "519965" `
 -start "0" `
 -limit "2" `
 -unused $False `
 -attributes ["completed", "usesleft"]

($output | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation ./testtt.csv)
```

Write-host $output produces:

```
@{tid=6; token=35ddmyQTlNpzLat; participant_info=} @{tid=7; token=nQ_S838LjYT4mR6; participant_info=}
```

Export-CSV produces:
[image]

This is what I need to produce from export-csv:
[image]

Can anybody please point me in the right direction to transforming the 'participant_info' into valid json for the CSV export? - As you can tell I have little expierence with PowerShell other then using it for SharePoint. Thank you!

Comment: That's not json.  $output looks like an object converted to a string by write-host.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your goal is to output an object with a custom set of properties (because it differs from the original object). This can be done with [Select-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.1) and calculated properties.

```
$output | 
    Select-Object tid,token,
        @{n='Firstname';e={$_.participant_info.Firstname}},
        @{n='Lastname';e={$_.participant_info.Lastname}},
        @{n='Email';e={$_.participant_info.Email}} |
            Export-CSV testtt.csv -NoType
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This works and I will research into Select-Object now <3